# Segula of Tefilin

Tags: tefilin, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, segulah

I was looking for some ideas to inspire people to start putting on tefilin everyday.

What are the advantages and blessings for a person who dons tefilin?

Comment: http://www.aish.com/jl/jewish-law/daily-living/18-Tefillin.html, https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/greatness-and-importance-of-mitzvah-of-tefillin/

Comment: Very nice and clear. Toda

Answer (score 1):

[**Menachot 44a**](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot_44a.20)

> ואמר ר"ל כל המניח תפילין מאריך ימים שנאמר (ישעיהו לח, טז) ה' עליהם יחיו ולכל בהן חיי רוחי ותחלימני והחייני:
>
> And Reish Lakish says: Anyone who dons phylacteries lives a long life, as it is stated: “The Lord is upon them, they will live, and altogether therein is the life of my spirit; and have me recover, and make me to live” (Isaiah 38:16). This is interpreted as referring to those who don phylacteries, which contain the name of the Lord, on their heads; as a result, they will live, be healed and merit long life.

Teffilin 2:20

> So says God: If you don Teffilin, I consider it as if you study Torah all day and night.